# What exactly is error "CALayer: ignoring bogus Layer Size"?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uikit, calayer

I am getting this error when one of the subview in UIScrollView is "too large". I use drawRect to draw this subview. Nothing is drawn when this warning appears as setNeedsDisplay() calls are ignored. Any idea what this means?

```
    -[<CALayer: 0x281719a00> display]: Ignoring bogus layer size (331759.000000, 132.000000), contentsScale 3.000000, backing store size (995277.000000, 396.000000)
```

Comment: It looks like you are setting a layer size to `331759 points` wide. Is that your intention?

Comment: Yes, I have a scroll view and a content view which can be zoomed to very high values.

Comment: @DonMag I guess there are limits on the bounds of UIView which has drawRect, even if I draw a small subrectangle in the overall bounds in drawRect. Similarly, I see there are limits to constant values in autolayout constraints as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71349375/autolayout-warning-nslayoutconstraint-is-being-configured-with-a-constant-that