# Autolayout warning "NSLayoutConstraint is being configured with a constant that exceeds internal limits"

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a subclass of UIScrollView called MyScrollView. There is a subview called *contentView* inside MyScrollView. The width constraint is set to be the contentSize of MyScrollView.

```
   private func setupSubviews() {
      contentView = ContentView()
      contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
      contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    
      self.addSubview(contentView)
    
      contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
      contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
      contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
      contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
      
      // create contentView's Width and Height constraints
      cvWidthConstraint = contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
      cvHeightConstraint = contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
           
    // activate them
      cvWidthConstraint.isActive = true
      cvHeightConstraint.isActive = true


      cvWidthConstraint.constant = myWidthConstant //<--- problem here if myWidthConstant is very high, such as 512000
      cvHeightConstraint.constant = frame.height
      contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

The problem is if later I set *cvWidthConstraint.constant* to a very high value such as 521000, I get a warning:

```
   This NSLayoutConstraint is being configured with a constant that exceeds internal limits.  A smaller value will be substituted, but this problem should be fixed. Break on BOOL _NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit(void) to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future.
```

I wonder how does one set UIScrollView content size to be very high values?

Comment: *"how does one set UIScrollView content size to be very high values?"* -- one doesn't. You need to describe what you're actually trying to do. No user is going to scroll 500-thousand points.

Comment: Well, a user can locally zoom 1000x at a point to scale the content and browse within the visible rect instead of whole scrollview. There are many use cases, such as viewing video frames at frame level in a 15 minute long video (30 frames/sec), or viewing audio samples with precision (there are 44100 float samples/sec).

Comment: Then you need to rethink your approach and only manage the frames needed to display.

Comment: That's what I am doing for one video or audio file. But when you have a complex timeline with multiple kinds of subviews in the scroll view, it becomes lot more complex.

Comment: *"it becomes lot more complex"* -- sure... that's why people get paid to do this. A 15-minute 30fps video is 27000 frames. Even if you *could* set a scroll view's content width to a large enough number, there's no way memory would support that many frame images.